# Undefined property: PlgAuthenticationmyauthplugin::$name in /somepath/www/libraries/src/Authentication/Authentication.php on line 184

Tags: joomla-4, authentication, bugs

I have made a custom login plugin for Joomla 3 and now for Joomla 4.
However, in Joomla 4, the login works as it should, but it generates a stack dump in the error log:

```
[Mon Jun 06 10:13:58.034860 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 100000:tid 140131864393280] [client 2a02:968:***:***:***:***:***:***:38362] AH01071: Got error '
PHP message: 
PHP Warning:  Undefined property: PlgAuthenticationhccxmlauthenticatie::$name in /disk/site/ontwikkel/joomla4-dev/www/libraries/src/Authentication/Authentication.
PHP on line 184
PHP message: 
PHP Stack trace:
PHP message: 
PHP   1. {main}() /disk/site/ontwikkel/joomla4-dev/www/index.
PHP:0
PHP message: 
PHP   2. require_once() /disk/site/ontwikkel/joomla4-dev/www/index.
PHP:32
PHP message: 
PHP   3. Joomla\\CMS\\Application\\CMSApplication->execute() /disk/site/ontwikkel/joomla4-dev/www/includes/app.
PHP:63
PHP message: 
PHP   4. Joomla\\CMS\\Application\\SiteApplication->doExecute() /disk/site/ontwikkel/joomla4-dev/www/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.
PHP:278
PHP message: 
PHP   5. Joomla\\CMS\\Application\\SiteApplication->dispatch($component = *uninitialized*) /disk/site/ontwikkel/joomla4-dev/www/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.
PHP:243
PHP message: 
PHP   6. Joomla\\CMS\\Component\\ComponentHelper::renderComponent($option = 'com_users', $params = *uninitialized*) /disk/site/ontwikkel/joomla4-dev/www/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.
PHP:204
PHP message: 
PHP   7. Joomla\\CMS\\Dispatcher\\ComponentDispatcher->dispatch() /disk/site/ontwikkel/joomla4-dev/www/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.
PHP:389
PHP message: 
PHP   8. Joomla\\CMS\\MVC\\Controller\\BaseController->execute($task = 'login') /disk/site/ontwikkel/joomla4-dev/www/libraries/src/Dispatcher/ComponentDispatcher.
PHP:146
PHP message: 
PHP   9. Joomla\\Component\\Users\\Site\\Controller\\UserController->login() /disk/site/ontwikkel/joomla4-dev/www/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.
PHP:735
PHP message: 
PHP  10. Joomla\\CMS\\Application\\SiteApplication->login($credentials = ['username' => '********', 'password' => '********', 'secretkey' => ''], $options = ['remember' => FALSE, 'return' => 'https://www.some.tld/']) /disk/site/ontwikkel/joomla4-dev/www/components/com_users/src/Controller/UserController.
PHP:122
PHP message: 
PHP  11. Joomla\\CMS\\Application\\CMSApplication->login($credentials = ['username' => '********', 'password' => '********', 'secretkey' => ''], $options = ['remember' => FALSE, 'return' => 'https://www.some.tld/', 'entry_url' => 'https://www.some.tld/index.
PHP?option=com_users&task=user.login', 'action' => 'core.login.site']) /disk/site/ontwikkel/joomla4-dev/www/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.
PHP:748
PHP message: 
PHP  12. Joomla\\CMS\\Authentication\\Authentication->authenticate($credentials = ['username' => '********', 'password' => '********', 'secretkey' => ''], $options = ['remember' => FALSE, 'return' => 'https://www.some.tld/', 'entry_url' => 'https://www.some.tld/index.
PHP?option=com_users&task=user.login', 'action' => 'core.login.site']) /disk/site/ontwikkel/joomla4-dev/www/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.
PHP:822', referer: https://www.some.tld/
```

How do I set the undefined property `$name`?

Comment: It's a J4 bug. You should report it to developers.

Comment: I will test if its also there with vanila installation to be continued

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was an Joomla bug, it was resolved after updating joomla to Joomla 4.2.3. I was on joomla 4.1.x

Comment: @mickmackusa i can't find specific bug, but i noticed it was resolved in version 4.2.3. i don't remember the exact version it was 4.1. but the witch point version i don't know

Answer (score -1):

You can Use this.

```
$name = $this->Auth->getUser();
```

that is all.

But to retrieve user's data other than id.
For more info see it.https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users

Comment: This answer was auto-flagged as "low-quality" due to its length.  Bas is asking how to implement a fix for `$name`.  Please [edit] your answer to give more generous insights.  Please understand that even if Bas knows how to implement your advice, the general public might not.  Stack Exchange answers should endeavour to help many people by educationally resolving one person's question.  Please take our [tour].

Comment: After an update joomla the issue was resolved so it was a joomla bug, sorry for the late response i was in the hospital